# Shiro 1.2 not working with Guice (and Vaadin)

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice, vaadin, shiro

First time user, please be kind!

I have a bit of a problem configuring Shiro to filter Vaadin-generated pages using Guice.

I have looked online on various websites including the Apache Shiro's guides and etc. Problem is that most websites tend to do it the 'old' fashion way, i.e. using Shiro 1.1 (which doesn't have native Guice support).

So here is the problem. My pages don't get filtered through Shiro. I have tried a zillion different things including using AOP for method authentication, setting filters up manually in the web.xml. Even setting up a shiro.ini file (which I do NOT want to do under any circumstances).

So here is the list of things I am using:
- Shiro 1.2.0-SNAPSHOT
- Guice 3.0
- Vaadin 6.7.4

Here is my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
                             http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

    <display-name>App</display-name>

    <context-param>
        <description>Vaadin production mode</description>
        <param-name>productionMode</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>guiceFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>guiceFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.app.GuiceServletInjector</listener-class>
    </listener>

</web-app>
```

Here is the Servlet Injector:

```
public class GuiceServletInjector extends GuiceServletContextListener {
    private ServletContext servletContext;

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
        servletContext = servletContextEvent.getServletContext();
        super.contextInitialized(servletContextEvent);
    }

    @Override
    protected Injector getInjector() {
        return Guice.createInjector(new GuiceServletModule(), new ShiroConfigurationModule(servletContext));
    }
```

Which then creates a ServletModule, which passes the request to the Vaadin app:

```
protected void configureServlets() {
    bind(Application.class).to(VaadinMainWindow.class).in(ServletScopes.SESSION);

    bind(BasicHttpAuthenticationFilter.class).in(Singleton.class);
    filter("/*").through(BasicHttpAuthenticationFilter.class);

    serve("/*", "*").with(VaadinApp.class);
}
```

Also during the injector stage, please notice that I create a ShiroConfigurationModule, which takes care of the realms and etc:

```
public class ShiroConfigurationModule extends ShiroWebModule {

    @Inject
    public ShiroConfigurationModule(ServletContext servletContext) {
        super(servletContext);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configureShiroWeb() {
        bindRealm().to(ShiroBaseRealm.class).in(Singleton.class);
        bind(Realm.class).to(ShiroBaseRealm.class).in(Singleton.class);

        processMethodInterceptors();
    }

    private void processMethodInterceptors() {
        MethodInterceptor interceptor = new AopAllianceAnnotationsAuthorizingMethodInterceptor();
        bindInterceptor(any(), annotatedWith(RequiresRoles.class), interceptor);
        bindInterceptor(any(), annotatedWith(RequiresPermissions.class), interceptor);
        bindInterceptor(any(), annotatedWith(RequiresAuthentication.class), interceptor);
        bindInterceptor(any(), annotatedWith(RequiresUser.class), interceptor);
        bindInterceptor(any(), annotatedWith(RequiresGuest.class), interceptor);
    }
}
```

The realm class returns 'true' for the supports(), but returns 'null' for everything, simulating that the user doesn't exists.

The chances of doing something wrong, or missing a step is very high. Can someone please care to explain what I'm missing so I can at least get a basic HTTP auth up?

Thanks a lot!
Mo.

Comment: Why are you using the filter-pattern `"/index.html"` instead of `"/*"` for `BasicHttpAuthenticationFilter`?

Comment: That was a test that I was doing. I have tried to do "/**" and "/*" and none of them have produced any results. I'll edit my post to reflect this. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Naturally the blog link has expired, and the site that is now redirected to contains no trace of that blog article whatsoever.

A copy of the article can be found here.

http://web.archive.org/web/20120413052117/http://www.mofirouz.com/wordpress/2012/01/guice-shiro-1-2-and-vaadingwt/

The crux of the answer: if you are using guice then you MUST include

```
filter("/*").through(GuiceShiroFilter.class)
```

in your ServletModule, or else NONE of the related shiro filters will ever get hit.

Answer (score -1):

Right so after a lot of testing and messing about with Shiro (as well as finally using the 1.2-release), I got mine to work.

I've written a detailed answer on my site (primarily because it is easier to write!).  Have a look:

http://www.mofirouz.com/wordpress/2012/01/guice-shiro-1-2-and-vaadingwt/

Good luck whoever out there!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.